# Let $F = \{2x-3:x \in E\}$. Show that $F$ is compact.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Suppose that $E$ is a compact nonempty subset of $\mathbb{R}$. Let $F = \{2x-3:x \in E\}$. Show that $F$ is compact.

My idea is to prove that $F$ is closed and bounded. To prove that it is closed, the limit exists and it is in $F$. To prove that $F$ is bounded, then $F$ has an infimum and supremum.

Comment: It’s just as easy to show that if $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ is any continuous function, then $f[E]=\{f(x):x\in E\}$ is compact. Your suggested approach will work, but a proof using open covers is at least as easy.

Comment: I agree with you.. I just don't like open covers, because I don't really get them.

Answer (score 2):

Let $f:x\mapsto 2x-3$ then $f$ is continuous and we have $F=f(E)$ is a compact as the image of a compact by a continuous function. See [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_space).

Comment: $\to +1^\uparrow \;\ddot\smile$

Answer (score 1):

Here are some ideas to try:

Suppose $M$ is a (nonnegative) upper bound on $E$; can you convince yourself that $2M - 3$ is an upper bound on $F$ as well? Now try something similar for a lower bound.

Now consider a sequence $x_n$ contained in $E$. What can you say about the sequence $2x_n - 3$, and in particular can you find its limit?